# Error [(?testMember@TestClass@@2MA) already defined in TestClass.obj] instead of it's not alrealdy definded !

Tags: c++, static

In the following class:

```
class TestClass
{
public:
     int staic testMember;
};

int TestClass::testMember;
```

I've got the following compiler error:

> error LNK2005: "public: static float TestClass::testMember" (?testMember@TestClass@@2MA) already defined in TestClass.obj

Note: I've tried to simulate the problem in a seperated application but everything worked well there.

I wonder where is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition:

```
int TestClass::testMember;
```

...is probably in the same H file as the declaration:

```
class TestClass
{
public:
     int staic testMember;
};
```

Move the definition to it's own CPP file.  You need to define it only once.

Comment: Actually I don't have any `.h` file

Comment: @Jack: do you include the file where the definition occurs ?

Comment: @Matthieu M: Sorry, which file ?

Comment: @Jack: the file where `int TestClass::testMember;` is should not be included in another file (bit simple, but good habit).